# VTiger Scheduled workflow: "is empty" condition doesen't work

Tags: php, workflow, crm, vtiger

I noticed that `is empty` and `is not empty` conditions don't work for scheduled workflows.

They work only for workflows triggered by hand (for example modifying a record), but scheduled workflows consider `not empty` all fields, also the empty ones..

The same behavior happens settig `is` condition and lefting blank the `value`: when the workflow is triggered by hand, it recognizes empty values, but when scheduled all fields are detected as `not empty`.

I'll do some more researches on it, but I'll apreciate if anyone could test and confirm this behaviour.
I've tested it also on a fresh 6.2 installation: the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to joebordes for his quick answer on [vTiger blog](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/1193150#Comment_1193150). He posted the fix to [GitHub](https://github.com/tsolucio/corebos/commit/33db17a1665af7834df798de4bf60a22b7347955):

Pratically, just find `modules/com_vtiger_workflow/WorkFlowScheduler.php` file and replace the line 136:

```
'is not empty' => 'n',
```

with those two lines:

```
'is empty' => 'y',
'is not empty' => 'ny',
```

Thanks all again!

Comment: This answer is valid for Vtiger 6.2. Let us know how works other versions!